# Starting Apache display errors

Tags: 12.04, apache2

Usually when i log in my system, apache automatically startup and works fine, today its not.

Then i try to start by `service apache2 start` then it displays following error.

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                     
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:8
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 * 
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

What could be the problem?Please Help me to solve this..

[My Apache Config File](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9227035/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and add follwing lines End of the file

`ServerName localhost`

This will set the server directive Globally.

Comment: This not solves my problem.Same error produces again.